# Property 'pname' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

I am working on an ionic app i am using firebase connectivity for it. 
I got my json from firebase but it giving me error in iterating it.
my provider.ts is as follow

```
export class MyProvider {
   masterdata : Array<any>;

   data : Array<any>;
  constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) {
   }

 getDataByPage() {
 return this.afd.list('/masterdata/0/page/').valueChanges();
 }
}
```

i want to pass it to diff pages my home.ts is

```
export class Home {
   home:Array<any>;
   data:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, public modalCtrl: ModalController,public masterdata: MyProvider ) {



    this.masterdata.getDataByPage().subscribe(result => {

    for(let i in result )
    {
        console.log(result[i]);
        if(result[i].pname == "Home")
        {
            this.data = result[i];
        }
    }

    });

  }
}
```

My json is

```
 this.masterdata= {
    page: [{
        "pname": "Home",
        "pagetitle": "Most Recent",
        "list": [{
            img: 'assets/img/01.png',
            isAnimated: false
        }, {
            img: 'assets/img/02.png',
            isAnimated: false
        }, {
            img: 'assets/img/02.png'
        }, {
            img: 'assets/img/03.png'
        }]
    },
    {
        "pname": "Profile",
        "img": "assets/img/user-img.png",
        "name": "Justin Timberlake",
        "email": "Justin Timberlake@yahoo.com"
    }, ]
}
```

it giving me error as following

```
Property 'pname' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Comment: Well you have spaces between result and [i] which might cause you problems. You could also create an interface to specifically describe the structure of result. Or you could make the for loop like so: for (let i in result as any) { }

Answer (score 0):

This should work `result [i]['pname']`.

Next try

```
let data = JSON.parse(result);
for(let i in data )
{
   console.log(data [i]);
   if(data [i].pname === "Home")
   {
     this.data = data [i];
   }
 }
```

Normal JSON looks like:

```
page: [{
    pname: "Home",
    pagetitle: "Most Recent",
```

Comment: its not workng for me. it showing identifier expected.

Answer (score 0):

This below condition you can change with Rxjs map operator. Check the response you are getting in console and update the logic accordingly. But make sure you have imported RxJS library.

```
this.masterdata.getDataByPage().subscribe(result => res.json()).map(result =>{

  console.log(res);
  if(res.pname == "Home")
  {
    this.data = res;
  }
});
```

Comment: what is data.json in this

Comment: Its should be .json()..RxJs operator to change incoming response to Json format

Comment: In console, what data are you getting..could you post it here?

Comment: if i use ur method it giving me above error while i was doing it was giving data of all pages but i want data for particular pages.

Comment: it giving me error like this. Cannot find name 'res'.